# Yii2 Can not Store huge integer

Tags: yii2

I want to store huge integer minimum 13 digit max 15 digit.

But every time it stored garbage.

My model is:

```
[['NIC'], 'integer'],
```

i also tried by safe & string validator but could not save correct number in database.

PS.
I am using Oracle and from oracle forms and from back end with insert query data is stored perfectly.

Comment: What do you mean by "garbage"? Show your code for saving & validating this value and the other code that works. Also is your system 32 or 64bit?

Comment: I mean only 10 random digits are saved. Using 64 Bit machine, OS both and PHP.

Comment: I found the problem. Actually i have installed wamp 3.0.6 64 bit but on task bar it shows wampmanager.exe *32 bit (with asterisk). has anyone idea about that ?